# What is 110813 in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the splash screen for Minecraft, there are random quotes that come up.  One is:

```
110813
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Didn't upvote because of the nice and pretty **42** (net) votes - I don't want to touch that :)

Comment: Can't argue with logic like that!

Comment: And I can't downvote it yet...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is a reference to the day [Notch got married](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splash), August 13th, 2011.

The linked page has explanations for all of the splash screen text, should that interest you.

Comment: This was one of the few I couldn't figure out.